# Ошибка. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /framework/core/image.php on line 12

Tags: php

На хостинге выдает ошибку

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/vhosts/ikirab.office-xxi.com/beejee.ikirab.office-xxi.com/framework/core/image.php on line 12
```

на локальной машине все в порядке

index.php

```
//директория приложения
define('APP_PATH', __DIR__);
define('FRAMEWORK_PATH', __DIR__ . '/../framework');

/*
показ ошибок - включен в режиме development
закомментировать для режима production
*/
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//входной скрипт
require_once(APP_PATH . '/app.php');
app::run();
```

image.php

```
<?php

        /**
         * Created by PhpStorm.
         * User: ikirab
         * Date: 10/12/16
         * Time: 11:40 AM
         */
        class image
        {

            public $path = APP_PATH . "/image/";
```

Это 12 строка, на которую ругаеться парсер

```
public $path = APP_PATH . "/image/";
```

`__DIR__` на хостинге это

```
/var/www/vhosts/ikirab.office-xxi.com/beejee.ikirab.office-xxi.com/app
```

Когда убираю `/var` такой ошибки не выдает, но не подключает файлы

Comment: 1. Версия PHP на сервере скорее всего меньше 5.6.0 в итоге конкатенация невозможна в свойстве класса. 2. Позабавил комментарий "Удалить в продакшене"- установите вывод ошибок в php.ini тестового сервера, а на боевом навсегда закройте, дабы не забывать исправить `ini_set`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.properties.php